# Bash script to copy a word from a text file and run it on terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, debian

So, I have a file named Words.txt

The third line of Words.txt looks as follows:(without quotes)

**"(7 spaces)My word is STACK"**

I want to dump **STACK** which exists in the Third Line of Words.txt in the terminal. Also,the word changes every day so I don't want to find the word.I just know that it is always in the third line and is always the fourth word.

Is there a way to dump this command **echo :STACK** in the terminal ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! SO isn't a code writing service, but we will do our best to help you fix/debug/improve code you have written. Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Well, to get the line, you could run `head -e Words.txt| tail -1`

Comment: @ echo off
wmic LOGICALDISK LIST BRIEF | find /i "UUI">USBDetails.txt

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%i in  (USBDetails.txt) do ( 
echo %%i
set USBDetails=%%i
set USBDetails=!USBDetails:~0,1!
echo USBDetails = !USBDetails!
echo !USBDetails! > Info.txt
dir !Info!.txt
)
pause

Comment: I wrote it in batch,

i want this to be in bash 
but the query is same as original question

Comment: Thank You FreshPow lets see if you can give me a bash script regarding original query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using `awk`, this can be very easy:

```
awk 'NR == 3 { print $4 }' /path/to/input
```

If you really want to solve this using pure Bash:

```
i=0
while read -r line; do
    ((++i == 15)) || continue
    arr=($line)
    echo ${arr[3]}
    break
done < /path/to/input
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.
janos bro you just made my day


huge love from india :)